# Cannot use table 'AspNetRoleClaims' for entity type 'IdentityRoleClaim<string>' since it is being used for entity type 'AspNetRoleClaims'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have been reading Stack Overflow for ages but I am a first time poster

Following on from one of the MS code examples, I have my typical identity SQL tables in Azure SQL as follows:

AspNetRoleClaims

AspNetRoles

AspNetUserClaims

AspNetUserLogins

AspNetUserRoles

AspNetUsers

AspNetUserTokens

A custom table called: Client which has a foreign key referencing the AspNetUsers table

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

in the startup some of my configurations are as below:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<SchoolContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext")));

services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false).AddEntityFrameworkStores<SchoolContext>();
```

the school context class:

```
public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }


modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");


modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>(entity =>
{
  entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });
});


modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRoles>(entity =>
{
  entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });
});

modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserTokens>(entity =>
{
  entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.Name });
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Client>(entity =>
{
  entity.HasKey(e => e.Client_ID).HasName("PK_Clients");

  entity.HasOne(d => d.AspNetUser_)
                .WithMany(p => p.Client)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.AspNetUser_Id)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Client_AspNetUsers");
});
```

Upon running the app, I get the following error message:

InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'AspNetRoleClaims' for entity type 'IdentityRoleClaim' since it is being used for entity type 'AspNetRoleClaims' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.

I'm not sure which other table the IdentityUserClaim class is mapped to, I have only specified the mapping once in the context class?

Comment: Maybe it will help to say that in my case I was trying to implement functionality that was already present in Identity Server 4. After removing these mappings and using ApplicationUserManager class instead I got user roles I wanted.